# No such file or directory npm error in docker-compose up command

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, package.json

I am almost new to `docker-compose`. I need to create a `yml` file, for creating and configuring my container, but I faced a npm error related when trying to run a container from my image.

I already have a container running, having these content:

```
node@7b822f0c11d8:/usr/src/osjs$ ls
CONTRIBUTING.md  LICENSE    dist                entrypoint.sh  package-lock.json  packages.json     src  webpack.config.js
Dockerfile       README.md  docker-compose.yml  node_modules   package.json       session-store.db  vfs
```

I have created an image from my container by using `docker commit` command.
Here is my image:

```
REPOSITORY    TAG          IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
hafez/hafez   version1.1   528fd0061a33   4 seconds ago   923MB
```

I put my yml and config files in `myDirectory`. Here is the output of `ls` in `myDirectory`:

```
config1.js  config2.js   my-docker-compose.yml
```

This is the `my-docker-compose.yml` content:

```
version: "3"

services:
  hafez:
    image: hafez/hafez:version1.1
    restart: always
    container_name: hafez
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./config1.js:/usr/src/osjs/src/client/config.js
      - ./config2.js:/usr/src/osjs/src/server/config.js
```

And here is the output of `docker-compose -f my-docker-compose.yml up`:

```
Creating hafez ... done
Attaching to hafez
hafez    | npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/osjs/package.json'
hafez    | npm WARN saveError EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/src/osjs/package-lock.json.1134850457'
hafez    | npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/osjs/package.json'
hafez    | npm WARN osjs No description
hafez    | npm WARN osjs No repository field.
hafez    | npm WARN osjs No README data
hafez    | npm WARN osjs No license field.
hafez    | 
hafez    | up to date in 1.506s
hafez    | found 0 vulnerabilities
hafez    | 
hafez    | npm ERR! code ENOENT
hafez    | npm ERR! syscall open
hafez    | npm ERR! path /usr/src/osjs/package.json
hafez    | npm ERR! errno -2
hafez    | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/osjs/package.json'
hafez    | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
hafez    | npm ERR! enoent 
hafez    | 
hafez    | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
hafez    | npm ERR!     /home/node/.npm/_logs/2021-09-17T11_15_37_791Z-debug.log
hafez    | npm ERR! code ENOENT
hafez    | npm ERR! syscall open
hafez    | npm ERR! path /usr/src/osjs/package.json
hafez    | npm ERR! errno -2
hafez    | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/osjs/package.json'
hafez    | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
hafez    | npm ERR! enoent 
hafez    | 
hafez    | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
hafez    | npm ERR!     /home/node/.npm/_logs/2021-09-17T11_15_38_196Z-debug.log
hafez    |   Usage: nodemon [nodemon options] [script.js] [args]
hafez    | 
hafez    |   See "nodemon --help" for more.
hafez    |
```

How can I fix this error and create/config container successfully?

Comment: Does it work fine if you launch the container manually i.e. with `docker run ...` command?

Comment: NO, It also won't work with `docker run`

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the way the image got created. Can you add some details on that?

Comment: I just create this with this command `docker commit 7b822f0c11d8 hafez/hafez:version1.1`

Comment: Reproducible workflows don't generally include `docker commit`.  Can you rebuild this image using a Dockerfile and the Compose `build:` setup instead?

Comment: I am not familiar with docker-files.  
@DavidMaze